# VB.NET can't use EOF and BOF with ADODB recordset

Tags: vb.net

In VB.net , EOF and BOD not working with ADODB recordset, even I added the right reference

```
DIM rsReqs as New ADODB.recordset
DIM cn as ADODB.connection
after open connection, with SQL Query I tryed to do this
rsReqs.open(StrSQL,cn)
```

Do until rsreqs.EOF
....
....

Thank's for your help

Comment: use Entity Framework instead

Comment: What does " not working"  mean?  Be explicit in your description of issues you are encountering.

Comment: If you're using VB.Net (and not VB6 or older, or VBA), why on *earth* are you using the older ADO COM libraries rather than ADO.Net, which is a standard part of .NET framework?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that libraries on vb.net, find the libraries based on your database server. Find more about how to connect your database (like mysql or access) with vb.net by googling.

Comment: You *can* use them but you *shouldn't*. They're COM libraries, not special in any way, and COM interop has been built into .NET since the start.